# One Solution, two WebForm Projects - accessing a page in one from the other. VS2019

Tags: asp.net, architecture, webforms, project, solution

I don't think there is an answer to this one but I'm often wrong, so fingers-crossed I am this time too.

(1)  In Visual Studio 2019 I have one Solution consisting of two Projects, both WebForms.

(2.1)  Project1 stores book information (but that's not really relevant).

(2.2)  Project2 logs to a database any exceptions caused by Project1. It has a single logFilter.aspx page, used to view those exceptions.

(3)  I've added a reference to Project2 in Project1 but this isn't about sharing code, so that's not really an issue either.

(4)  My question is, when I navigate to Project1 in a browser, is there any way I can access the logFilter.aspx page in Project2?

(5)  Right now for example, I have to change the Solution's Properties to make both Projects "startup projects". Then I can access them both separately - in separate browser windows - like so:

(5.1)  https://localhost:44340/bookPage.aspx     (Project1)

(5.2)  https://localhost:44389/logFilter.aspx    (Project2)

(6)  That works fine on my local machine during development. But I really don't see how it could work once I've deployed the lot to my web hosting company's IIS (at [www.Project1.com](http://www.Project1.com) for example) on the Internet.

(7)  I could add the logFilter.aspx page to Project1. But then I would have different versions of it dotted around all my future projects.

(8)  I've searched Microsoft Docs and StackOverflow but the few answers I've found seem to be MVC-related. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364340/how-to-integrate-two-different-website-projects-under-one-solution) does seems to provide an answer by adding a key to web.config like so:

```
   <add key="WebsiteURL" value="http://localhost:2030/" />

   and then using:

   Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebsiteURL"] + "SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx");
```

I'm no expert but I'm assuming that I wouldn't have that Port information once I'd deployed it to a web hosting company's web server on the Internet.

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194921/multiple-vs-projects-in-one-solution)  suggests that you either make one project the child of another or that you use virtual folders on IIS which I doubt I would have access to.

Strange, as I would have thought this would have been quite a common practice for developers to want to do. Still, any thoughts anyone has would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a setup that might work better is that you have a solution with two projects. Project1 is the webapp BUT PROJECT2 is a library.

Now when you get an exception on project1 you can call the class/function what you might need in project2 and log the information.

future projects (3,4,...etc) can still reference project2 for logging purposes.

Comment: Hi NicoTek, thanks very much for your thoughts. I think you're right. The only downside is that, in my logging project I envisage a web page which would be used to filter the exceptions and you can't have a web page in a class library (unless you know different?). So I'll just have to copy that page into all future projects... and should I need to change its structure for some reason, I'll have to change it in many different projects. A shame but, there you are. Thanks again :)